# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Decimal' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I'm getting the error in the title "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Decimal' is not valid." from this line of code

```
_event.TotalDollars = IIf((dr("TotalDollars") Is DBNull.Value), "$0", CType(dr("TotalDollars"), Decimal).ToString("c"))
```

`_event.TotalDollars` is a string

Why is the third part of IIF statement ever getting evaluated?   The whole point of this IIF is so that DBNull values are not attempted to be converted into Decimals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

`IIF` evaluates both the True and False operations before returning.

Depending on which version of VS you have you could just use `If(condition,true,false)` instead (which doesn't)

Also, you're probably better to use `IsDbNull(condition)` to do the test.

Comment: That's because `IIF` is just a standard function call, correct?

Answer (score 1):

using DatasetExtensions you could also just do this with a nullable decimal type.

```
_event.TotalDollars = if(dr.Field(of Decimal?)("TotalDollars"),0).ToString("c")
```